# The "swiperight" event cannot be bound because Hammer.JS is not loaded

Tags: angular, hammer.js, angular10

What is the proper configuration for HammerJS in Angular 10/11?

We shouldn't import from 'hammerjs' anymore, instead, we should import `HammerModule` from `@angular/platform-browser`. This doesn't seem to work.

When I try to set up HammerJS like that:

```typescript
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import {
      BrowserModule,
      HammerGestureConfig,
      HammerModule,
      HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG
    } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
    
    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
    import { HelloComponent } from "./hello.component";
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HammerModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
          useClass: HammerGestureConfig
        }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

I get this console message when I try to use swiperight:

> The "swiperight" event cannot be bound because Hammer.JS is not loaded
> and no custom loader has been specified.

Here is a StackBlitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zyv6hq?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.module.ts)

I can't make it work without adding 'hammerjs' import.
I thought that importing HammerModule (with default HammerGestureConfig) should be enough to make it work.

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rdfg9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) (but with the use of import 'hammerjs').

Comment: https://indepth.dev/gestures-in-an-angular-application#swipe

Comment: I've seen that @Chellappan வ, thanks. But it uses import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs', which shouldn't be needed now with HammerModule in Angular 10/11.

Comment: @Chellappanவ this is the only way I could make this work... this is very strange, since HammerJS should work by default in Angular 10/11

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/HammerModule):

> Note that applications still need to include the HammerJS script itself. This module simply sets up the coordination layer between HammerJS and Angular's EventManager.

So doing `import 'hammerjs'` is still needed.